# Geometric Matrix Transformations

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
r = rectangle('Position', [1 2 4 6])
axis([0 15 0 15])
```

I know how to create a transformation matrix and how to store it as an `affine2d` geometric transformation object.

However, my issue comes with multiplying the rectangle object with the transformation matrix.

Is there a way to multiply the rectangle object created above with the transformation matrix to get a resultant translated rectangle?

Comment: `affine2d` transforms coordinates, but your `r` is a graphics object. For transforming a graphics object you need [`hgtransform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgtransform.html).

Comment: Okay so I changed my approach and did the following:

```X = [-2 -2 4 4];
Y = [-2 2 2 -2];
hRectangle = fill(X,Y, 'k');

thetad = 90;
R = [cosd(thetad) -sind(thetad); sind(thetad) cosd(thetad)];
C = repmat([0 0], 4, 1)';
axis([-5 5 -5 5])

V = get(hRectangle, 'Vertices')';
V = R*(V - C) + C;
    
set(hRectangle, 'Vertices',V')```

The resulting transformation differs from the result achieved through manual multiplication of the matrices. However, I'm not sure which is correct between the two. Is the above approach correct?